# Show progress bar without controls in YouTube video embed

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to hide the controls and only show the progress bar for an embedded YouTube video?

`controls=0` hides the controls, but it also takes away the progress bar.

*Secondary question:*
Alternatively, is it possible to not show controls when the video starts and only show them on mouse hover?